# Xquery using FLWOR Expression Query

Tags: xml, debugging, xquery, flwor

I have the following xml structure :

```
<reviews>
<review>
    <review_no>R1</review_no>
    <movie_title>After.Life</movie_title>
    <rating>3</rating>
    <reviewer>John Frankenheimer</reviewer>
    <review_date>2012-11-07</review_date>
    <review_desc>Average</review_desc>
</review>
    ...
</reviews>
```

and the following XQuery :

```
<query2>
{
for $r in distinct-values(doc("reviews.xml")/reviews/review/reviewer)

return
    <output><reviewer> {data(parent::node()/movie_title)} </reviewer>
    </output>
}
</query2>
```

The output I get is series of

```
<output><reviewer/></output>
```

inside `<query2>` tags, when instead reviewer tags should contain movie_title data.

Why ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case your XQuery processor does not support `group by`, you will need to perform an (implicit) join. Very similar to your query, but fetch all reviewers and for each, query the reviewers using a predicate.

```
<query2>
  <output>
    {
      for $reviewer in distinct-values(doc("reviews.xml")/reviews/review/reviewer)
      return <reviewer>
               {
                 /reviews/review[reviewer = $reviewer]/movie_title
               }
             </reviewer>
    }
  </output>
</query2>
```

Answer (score 1):

`distinct-values` returns only values, not nodes, so `parent::node()` does not work.

What is your expected output? You didn't specify your real problem. I guess you want to find all movie_titles grouped by reviewer. If so, `group by` will be very helpful for you:

```
<query2>
  <output>
    {
      for $review in doc("reviews.xml")/reviews/review
      let $reviewer := $review/reviewer
      group by $reviewer
      return <reviewer>{$review/movie_title}</reviewer>
    }
  </output>
</query2>
```

If you do not want the `<movie_title/>`-tags, you can wrap `data()` around `$review/movie_title`.

Comment: xmlspy doesn't recongnize group by keyword.

Comment: Better add your Query processor if it's less capable next time. I added a solution not using `group by` as another answer as it is another way to solve your problem. `group by` should be preferred anyway, if supported.

Comment: Ranon : 

Why doesn't parent :: node work for this code 
`<query2>
{
 for $m in doc("movies.xml")//genre
    where lower-case(data($m)) = "drama" 
 return <b>{data(parent::node()/title)}</b> 
    
}
</query2>`

Comment: Cannot tell you without any data. But looks like you could do this query without any flwor expression, only using predicates.

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your query is that a FLWOR expression does not set the context item: so instead of parent::node(), you need $r/parent-node().

This is a very easy mistake to make if you are used to XSLT, and I make it all the time.